# Numeric keyboard not working with TextInputLayout (In Dialog)

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I face the strange issue in my TextInputLayout.

**My problem:**

If I give the input type "text" It working correctly.

But If I give the input type "number" it just showing keyboard. But not able to enter the number in edittext.

**My xml code:**

```
       <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/tl_age"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tl_dob"
                app:layout_marginLeftPercent="2%">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/patient_age"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
                    android:hint="Age"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="3"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:minHeight="@dimen/min_ed_height"
                    />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**What I am tried:**

1. Set TextInputType from Java code -->  mEtAge.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
2. Previously I use the Edittext now TextInputEditText
3. Set TextChange listener (for testing) -> But textChange listener not triggered.
4. Searched in Google & SO. No similar questions found.

**Java code:**

I use this code in my Dialog(android.app.Dialog).

```
public void showBookAppointmentDialog(final Activity activity){
      mDialog = new Dialog(activity,android.R.style.Theme_Light_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
      mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
      mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.sv_existinguser_appointment);
      mDialog.setCancelable(false);
      mEtAge = (TextInputEditText) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.patient_age);
      .....
      }
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Really strange. I have implemented the same way and it's working fine.

Comment: post your java code here

Comment: @warlock java code updated

Comment: @MD are you tried with dialog??? In Dialog only I got problem. But in activity it working fine.

Comment: @RanjithKumar Oh yes with `DialogFragment`.

Comment: @Ranjithkumar did you find a solution by any chance?

Comment: @rdias002 It's hack.. Place your TextInputLayout into LinearLayout. 

< LinearLayout> 
< TextInputLayout/> 
</LinearLayout>

Comment: @Ranjithkumar, thanks for the reply. The solution in my case was that I had set an OnKeyListener to the dialog and was returning true. For some reason numeric keys trigger the OnKeyListener and thus wasn't typing.

Comment: @rdias002 post your answer. It will helpful for someone

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by OP, here is what fixed the issue for me.

I had set an OnKeyListener to my dialog in which I was returning true. And for some reason the numeric keys trigger this OnKeyListener and thus wasn't typing.

So I changed the listener to return false when my condition isn't satisfied which solved the issue for me.

```
dialog?.setOnKeyListener { _, keyCode, event ->
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if (!getNavController().popBackStack()) {
            dismissAllowingStateLoss()
            return@setOnKeyListener true
        }
    }
    false
}
```